# VS Code - debugging referenced project (.NET Core)

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, vscode-debugger

How can I force debbuger in Visual Studio Code to step into method which is defined in project which I added reference to? I am referencing Encog library which is outside the working directory like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
      <RootNamespace>IDS_CS</RootNamespace>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\encog-dotnet-core-master\encog-core-cs\encog-core-cs.csproj" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Debugger starts and everything seems fine, however I cannot step into method which is implemented in the Encog librarye.

Any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all of your `*.csproj` (C# project) files that you want to [debug in **vs-code**](https://74th.github.io/vscode-debug-specs/csharp/), be sure to add the **`<DebugType>portable</DebugType>`** in a `<PropertyGroup>` option. Below is a snippet of how I have all of my `*.csproj` files setup.  After doing this I was able to debug step-into the main web application as well as any of the code referenced from one of my other projects to support separation of concerns: my logic lair layer :) vs. my model layer vs. my data layer, etc.

**In all your `*.csproj` files:**

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

A bit more info can be [found here if you have `project.json` files](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Portable-PDBs#net-cli-projects-projectjson) instead of `*.csproj` files.